# Facebook post to newsfeed dont show FB is not defined

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

Im trying to post to facebook newsfeed and the popupbox doesn't show up from time to time.
I think it has to do with postbacks or something.
This is whats happen: 
The users bye something and get send to Payson (payson is Swedish version of Paypal) in a popup window and then payson send the user back to my page still in the popup window.
This is a code that runs:

```
function postToFeed() {

try {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {

            var obj = {
                method: 'feed',
                link: 'link',
                picture: 'imagelink',
                name: 'title',
                caption: 'some text...',
                description: 'some text...',
                redirect_uri: 'url'
            };

            function callback(response) {
                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
            }

            FB.ui(obj, callback);
        }
        else {
            alert("not connected")
        }
    });

} catch (e) {
    alert(e.Message)
}
 }
```

Now whats happen is that i get the error from my try catch and it's just sayin **FB is not defined** .

If i run this function with a button afterwards it's working just fine.
If i fake the postback from payson it's also working, but not if i do it in a new window.

I tried to put the FB.init function in my function but that didn't help.

Thanks for your help!

**New Code**

This is in a .js file

```
var isLoaded = false;
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
FB.init({
    appId: '00000000', // App ID
    channelUrl: 'url', // Channel File
    status: true, // check login status
    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML
    oauth: true // enable OAuth
});

isLoaded = true;
 };

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function (d) {
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   } (document));

   (function (d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/sv_SE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=503537396325197";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


FB.init({ appId: "000", status: true, cookie: true });


   function postToFeed() {

    var obj = {
        display: 'iframe',
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'url',
        picture: 'url',
        name: 'text',
        caption: 'text',
        description: 'text',
        redirect_uri: 'url'
    };

    function callback(response) {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
   }


   function init() {
    FB.init({
    appId: '00000',
    status: true, // check login status
    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml: true, // parse XFBML
    channelUrl: 'url', // custom channel
    oauth: true // enable OAuth
     });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
        var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
        var access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken
        var page_id = "00000"; //page id
        var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id =" + page_id + " and uid=" + user_id;
        var the_query = FB.Data.query(fql_query);

        the_query.wait(function (rows) {

            if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                $("#container").show();
                $("#container_notlike").hide();
                $("#notloggedin").hide();

            }

            else {
                $("#container_notlike").show();
                $("#container").hide();
                $("#notloggedin").hide();

                login();
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("#container_notlike").hide();
        $("#container").hide();

        login();

    }
     });

     }

      init();

       // whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
     FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
     top.location.href = "url";
   });


    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) {
      top.location.href = "url";
     });




      function login() {
     FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log('Logged in');
        } else {
        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
       }, { scope: 'email,user_likes,publish_actions' });
       }



    function likereload() {

    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {

      top.location.href = "url"
       });

   }


    function getuserinfo() {

       FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
          if (response.authResponse) {

           FB.api('/me', function (response) {
            document.getElementById("txtfName").value = response.first_name;
            document.getElementById("txtlName").value = response.last_name;
            document.getElementById("txtemail").value = response.email;

            });

         }
      });


       }
```

Comment: well...you call FB.init 3 (!!!) times in this code...only the very first one should be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem,

```
window.setTimeout('postToFeed()', 3000);
```

Then all facebook code have time to load before i bring up the feed dialog

Answer (score 0):

"FB is not defined" means that you did not load/initialize the JavaScript SDK.

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

See "Loading and Initialization" of an example how to use the JavaScript SDK, don´t put anything of that in your custom function.

Also, you don´t need "getLoginStatus", the feed dialog also works without a user login so calling "getLoginStatus" is senseless and just takes time. I would also remove the try/catch block, you don´t need it.

Comment: And sometimes the fb is not defined error shows up but then the share box desides to show up like magic, on the same time.
I know i shouldn't need these things i was just desperate.  

I tried to do it in jquery document ready but that didn't work ether

Comment: then it gets called somewhere. please take a look at the link i posted, everything you need to add is there.

Comment: Yes thank you i have read that page, it's working fine when i pop up the sharebox with a button, but i want it to pop up when the page load automatically. That's the isue.

Comment: well, those ui dialogs should only be used on mouse events (like "click"), they should not be opened immediately without any user interaction. anyway, you would just need to call FB.ui right after FB.init. Right where it says "Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here" in the sample code.

Comment: Yes i know it's a button that runs asp.net code and then pops up the feed dialog.

  `share.Text = "<script type='text/javascript'>postToFeed();</script>";
                share.Visible = true;`

When i put the code in here " // Additional initialization code here" It does't work, not even the button

Comment: post your full code an i can tell you why. not much experience with asp.net, but that´s not the problem here anyway.